# How can I use gRPC Health Checking Protocol in C++ to monitor server health for specific services?

Tags: health-check, grpc-c++

So I was exploring how to monitor the health of gRPC C++ server and found the gRPC Health Checking Protocol. But I am a bit confused as to how to use it in C++.

So, there is this function `grpc::EnableDefaultHealthCheckService(true);` which seems to expose the health of an empty string service, but it not clear to me how this endpoint works (i.e. in which case does it answer SERVING or NOT_SERVING) ?

And is there a simple way to expose a HealthCheckService for a specific service (i.e. one of my own implemented service) ? I can't find any clear examples.

Thanks

Did already check this post:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13962